# How to create a singletone of SharedPreferences and then create different files?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a singleton for `SharedPreferences` the thing is, I was using only one `SharedPreferences` filename, but now I'd like to have something like : 
`login_preferences` or `settings_preferences`, what's the correct way to create them and have them singleton? Or do I have to create a class one per each like `LoginSharedPreferences` and another for `SettingsSharedPreferences` and do the operations there?

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` objects obtained via Android APIs are, inherently, singletons.

If you use [PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)) you of course get a single, shared object.

If you use [Context#getSharedPreferences("filename", MODE)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)), you will get one object per file name:

> **Only one instance of the SharedPreferences object is returned to any callers for the same name**, meaning they will see each other's edits as soon as they are made.

So you can do what you want:

```
// One class
val loginPrefs = getSharedPreferences("login_preferences", 0)

// Another class
val loginPrefs2  = getSharedPreferences("login_preferences", 0) // Same "singleton" object
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have create two Singleton classes with different names and access like you said.

```
public class LoginAppState {

    private static final String SETTINGS_NAME = "LoginPrfs";

    private static LoginAppState sSharedPrefs;

    private final SharedPreferences mPref;

    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

    private boolean mBulkUpdate = false;

    /**
     * Enum representing your setting names or key for your setting.
     */
    public enum Key {
        /* Recommended naming convention:
         * ints, floats, doubles, longs:
         * SAMPLE_NUM or SAMPLE_COUNT or SAMPLE_INT, SAMPLE_LONG etc.
         *
         * boolean: IS_SAMPLE, HAS_SAMPLE, CONTAINS_SAMPLE
         *
         * String: SAMPLE_KEY, SAMPLE_STR or just SAMPLE
         */

        TOKEN_STR,
        EMAIL_STR,
        MEMBERID_STR,
        NAME_STR,
    }

    private LoginAppState(Context context) {
        mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    public static LoginAppState getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sSharedPrefs == null) {
            sSharedPrefs = new LoginAppState(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sSharedPrefs;
    }

    public static LoginAppState getInstance() {
        if (sSharedPrefs != null) {
            return sSharedPrefs;
        }

        //Option 1:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Should use getClient(Context) at least once before using this method.");

        //Option 2:
        // Alternatively, you can create a new instance here
        // with something like this:
        // getClient(MyCustomApplication.getAppContext());
    }

    public void put(Key key, String val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putString(key.name(), val);
        doCommit();
    }

    public void put(Key key, int val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putInt(key.name(), val);
        doCommit();
    }

    public void put(Key key, boolean val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putBoolean(key.name(), val);
        doCommit();
    }

    public void put(Key key, float val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putFloat(key.name(), val);
        doCommit();
    }

    public void put(Key key, Set<String> set) {
        synchronized (this) {
            doEdit();
            mEditor.remove(AppState.Key.WISHLIST.name());
            doCommit();
            doEdit();
            mEditor.putStringSet(key.name(), set);
            doCommit();
        }

    }

    public void putContestSet(Key key, Set<String> set) {
        synchronized (this) {
            doEdit();
            mEditor.remove(Key.CONTESTLIST.name());
            doCommit();
            doEdit();
            mEditor.putStringSet(key.name(), set);
            doCommit();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for storing doubles.
     * <p/>
     * There may be instances where the accuracy of a double is desired.
     * SharedPreferences does not handle doubles so they have to
     * cast to and from String.
     *
     * @param key The enum of the preference to store.
     * @param val The new value for the preference.
     */
    public void put(Key key, double val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putString(key.name(), String.valueOf(val));
        doCommit();
    }

    public void put(Key key, long val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putLong(key.name(), val);
        doCommit();
    }

    public String getString(Key key, String defaultValue) {
        return mPref.getString(key.name(), defaultValue);
    }

    public String getString(Key key) {
        return mPref.getString(key.name(), null);
    }

    public int getInt(Key key) {
        return mPref.getInt(key.name(), 0);
    }

    public int getInt(Key key, int defaultValue) {
        return mPref.getInt(key.name(), defaultValue);
    }

    public long getLong(Key key) {
        return mPref.getLong(key.name(), 0);
    }

    public long getLong(Key key, long defaultValue) {
        return mPref.getLong(key.name(), defaultValue);
    }

    public float getFloat(Key key) {
        return mPref.getFloat(key.name(), 0);
    }

    public float getFloat(Key key, float defaultValue) {
        return mPref.getFloat(key.name(), defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for retrieving doubles.
     * <p/>
     * There may be instances where the accuracy of a double is desired.
     * SharedPreferences does not handle doubles so they have to
     * cast to and from String.
     *
     * @param key The enum of the preference to fetch.
     */
    public double getDouble(Key key) {
        return getDouble(key, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for retrieving doubles.
     * <p/>
     * There may be instances where the accuracy of a double is desired.
     * SharedPreferences does not handle doubles so they have to
     * cast to and from String.
     *
     * @param key The enum of the preference to fetch.
     */
    public double getDouble(Key key, double defaultValue) {
        try {
            String string = mPref.getString(key.name(), String.valueOf(defaultValue));
            if (string == null) {
                return defaultValue;
            }
            return Double.valueOf(string);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(Key key, boolean defaultValue) {
        return mPref.getBoolean(key.name(), defaultValue);
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(Key key) {
        return mPref.getBoolean(key.name(), false);
    }

    public Set<String> getSet(Key key) {
        return mPref.getStringSet(key.name(), new HashSet<>());
    }

    /**
     * Remove keys from SharedPreferences.
     *
     * @param keys The enum of the key(s) to be removed.
     */
    public void remove(Key... keys) {
        doEdit();
        for (Key key : keys) {
            mEditor.remove(key.name());
        }
        doCommit();
    }

    /**
     * Remove all keys from SharedPreferences.
     */
    public void clear() {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.clear();
        doCommit();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return getString(Key.TOKEN_STR) != null;
    }

    public void edit() {
        mBulkUpdate = true;
        mEditor = mPref.edit();
    }

    public void commit() {
        mBulkUpdate = false;
        mEditor.commit();
        mEditor = null;
    }

    private void doEdit() {
        if (!mBulkUpdate && mEditor == null) {
            mEditor = mPref.edit();
        }
    }

    private void doCommit() {
        if (!mBulkUpdate && mEditor != null) {
            mEditor.commit();
            mEditor = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and your SettingsAppState.java looks like this

```
public class SettingsAppState {

    private static final String SETTINGS_NAME = "SettingsPrfs";

    private static SettingsAppState sSharedPrefs;

    private final SharedPreferences mPref;

    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

    private boolean mBulkUpdate = false;

    /**
     * Enum representing your setting names or key for your setting.
     */
    public enum Key {
        /* Recommended naming convention:
         * ints, floats, doubles, longs:
         * SAMPLE_NUM or SAMPLE_COUNT or SAMPLE_INT, SAMPLE_LONG etc.
         *
         * boolean: IS_SAMPLE, HAS_SAMPLE, CONTAINS_SAMPLE
         *
         * String: SAMPLE_KEY, SAMPLE_STR or just SAMPLE
         */

        TOKEN_STR,
        EMAIL_STR,
        MEMBERID_STR,
        NAME_STR,
    }

    private SettingsAppState(Context context) {
        mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    public static SettingsAppState getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sSharedPrefs == null) {
            sSharedPrefs = new AppState(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sSharedPrefs;
    }

    public static SettingsAppState getInstance() {
        if (sSharedPrefs != null) {
            return sSharedPrefs;
        }

        //Option 1:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Should use getClient(Context) at least once before using this method.");

        //Option 2:
        // Alternatively, you can create a new instance here
        // with something like this:
        // getClient(MyCustomApplication.getAppContext());
    }

    public void put(Key key, String val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putString(key.name(), val);
        doCommit();
    }

    public void put(Key key, int val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putInt(key.name(), val);
        doCommit();
    }

    public void put(Key key, boolean val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putBoolean(key.name(), val);
        doCommit();
    }

    public void put(Key key, float val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putFloat(key.name(), val);
        doCommit();
    }

    public void put(Key key, Set<String> set) {
        synchronized (this) {
            doEdit();
            mEditor.remove(AppState.Key.WISHLIST.name());
            doCommit();
            doEdit();
            mEditor.putStringSet(key.name(), set);
            doCommit();
        }

    }

    public void putContestSet(Key key, Set<String> set) {
        synchronized (this) {
            doEdit();
            mEditor.remove(Key.CONTESTLIST.name());
            doCommit();
            doEdit();
            mEditor.putStringSet(key.name(), set);
            doCommit();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for storing doubles.
     * <p/>
     * There may be instances where the accuracy of a double is desired.
     * SharedPreferences does not handle doubles so they have to
     * cast to and from String.
     *
     * @param key The enum of the preference to store.
     * @param val The new value for the preference.
     */
    public void put(Key key, double val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putString(key.name(), String.valueOf(val));
        doCommit();
    }

    public void put(Key key, long val) {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.putLong(key.name(), val);
        doCommit();
    }

    public String getString(Key key, String defaultValue) {
        return mPref.getString(key.name(), defaultValue);
    }

    public String getString(Key key) {
        return mPref.getString(key.name(), null);
    }

    public int getInt(Key key) {
        return mPref.getInt(key.name(), 0);
    }

    public int getInt(Key key, int defaultValue) {
        return mPref.getInt(key.name(), defaultValue);
    }

    public long getLong(Key key) {
        return mPref.getLong(key.name(), 0);
    }

    public long getLong(Key key, long defaultValue) {
        return mPref.getLong(key.name(), defaultValue);
    }

    public float getFloat(Key key) {
        return mPref.getFloat(key.name(), 0);
    }

    public float getFloat(Key key, float defaultValue) {
        return mPref.getFloat(key.name(), defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for retrieving doubles.
     * <p/>
     * There may be instances where the accuracy of a double is desired.
     * SharedPreferences does not handle doubles so they have to
     * cast to and from String.
     *
     * @param key The enum of the preference to fetch.
     */
    public double getDouble(Key key) {
        return getDouble(key, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for retrieving doubles.
     * <p/>
     * There may be instances where the accuracy of a double is desired.
     * SharedPreferences does not handle doubles so they have to
     * cast to and from String.
     *
     * @param key The enum of the preference to fetch.
     */
    public double getDouble(Key key, double defaultValue) {
        try {
            String string = mPref.getString(key.name(), String.valueOf(defaultValue));
            if (string == null) {
                return defaultValue;
            }
            return Double.valueOf(string);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(Key key, boolean defaultValue) {
        return mPref.getBoolean(key.name(), defaultValue);
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(Key key) {
        return mPref.getBoolean(key.name(), false);
    }

    public Set<String> getSet(Key key) {
        return mPref.getStringSet(key.name(), new HashSet<>());
    }

    /**
     * Remove keys from SharedPreferences.
     *
     * @param keys The enum of the key(s) to be removed.
     */
    public void remove(Key... keys) {
        doEdit();
        for (Key key : keys) {
            mEditor.remove(key.name());
        }
        doCommit();
    }

    /**
     * Remove all keys from SharedPreferences.
     */
    public void clear() {
        doEdit();
        mEditor.clear();
        doCommit();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return getString(Key.TOKEN_STR) != null;
    }

    public void edit() {
        mBulkUpdate = true;
        mEditor = mPref.edit();
    }

    public void commit() {
        mBulkUpdate = false;
        mEditor.commit();
        mEditor = null;
    }

    private void doEdit() {
        if (!mBulkUpdate && mEditor == null) {
            mEditor = mPref.edit();
        }
    }

    private void doCommit() {
        if (!mBulkUpdate && mEditor != null) {
            mEditor.commit();
            mEditor = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you set and access data from `LoginAppState` form your `Activity`.

```
LoginAppState mLoginAppState = LoginAppState.getInstance(this);
mLoginAppStateput(LoginAppState.Key.NAME_STR,"Stuart DTO");
mLoginAppStateput(LoginAppState.Key.EMAIL_STR,"stauart@stackoverflow.com");
```

For accessing the data from `LoginAppState` from your `Activity`.

```
LoginAppState mLoginAppState = LoginAppState.getInstance(this);
mLoginAppState.getString(AppState.Key.NAME_STR,"defualt_value");
mLoginAppState.getString(AppState.Key.EMAIL_STR,"defualt_value");
```

Comment: what's mBulk there?

Comment: its to stop editing the SharedPrefrence if you are trying to access in other threads but , but it's default `false`. You can neglect it please find my updated answer on how to set and get data.